Stop wear os app from going to the background
I'm developing a wear os app and have the following issue:
When the watch goes dark (either by timeout or by the palm gesture) and I turn my wrist or tap the watch, I'm back at the home screen with my watch face.
What I would like instead, is that I'm back in my app where I left off.
I don't need the app to stay on all the time, nor do I collect any continious data. So it's okay that the screen goes black and "pauses" the app, I just want to get back to where I was before the screen went dark.
I can manually go to the recent apps and select my app. Then I'm back where I left off and everything is working as expected.
What's really confusing to me, is how I should change my code so that either my app never goes to the background or comes back to the foreground when my watch is turned on again.
I have tried the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON and this works as a workaround. The watch will never time out but the palm gesture will still turn the screen off and I have the same issues as described above. And It's unnecessarily consuming battery power.
I have also tried a broadcast receiver. But I couldn't get it to work, the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON was never triggered. I assume because my app was in the background.
I have also read about always on apps: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/always-on. But I'm not sure that this is also the best approach in my case? Since I don't need the app to always be on. But I thought about implementing the always on feature and simply don't set any content when it goes itno ambient mode.
What's the best approach for my use case?

It may be more that this is how your watch behaves. How many Wear OS device models have you tested?

@CommonsWare I have only tested it ony ma Galaxy Watch 7. But other apps behave exactly like I want mine to behave. For example Strava:
I start a workout and after a few seconds (or by using the palm gesture) the screen turns off. When I wake up the watch again I get back to where I left off. Okay Strava probably collects data (GPS) in the background which my app doesn't need to but other from that this is the behaviour i would like for my app.

Probably is deprecated, but it's a start for some research: wear os used to have a AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider class which used to keep the app in foreground even when then screen goes off, plus it gives a callback for when the aod mode is turned on
